# Combine count and max in postgresql sql

Tags: postgresql, count, max

I have a problem to formulate an sql question in postgresql, hoping to get some help here

I have a table called visitor that contains an column called `fk_employee_id`, `fk_employee_id` contains different number between 1-10, example:

```
1,3,4,6,4,6,7,3,2,1,6,7,6
```

Now I want to find out which value that is the most frequent in this column (in this case 6) I have made an question that seem to solve my question;

```
SELECT fk_employee_id
FROM visitor
GROUP BY fk_employee_id
ORDER BY COUNT(fk_employee_id) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

but this question, doesn't get right if it is two values that are the most frequent one. So instead I try to write a question which contains max function but cant figure out how, anyone now how to do this?

Comment: @StuartLC This is the question, namely how to return more than one `fk_employee_id` should two or more be tied for having the highest count.

Comment: @StuartLC Tell me about it; sadly this is the case with the majority of questions I see these days :~(

Comment: Hi, yes if there are two values that are most frequent i want that to return, example value 5 and 6 are the most frequent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `RANK` here to slightly modify your current query:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        fk_employee_id,
        RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rank
    FROM visitor
    GROUP BY fk_employee_id
)

SELECT fk_employee_id
FROM cte
WHERE rank = 1;
```

### Demo

Comment: Thx Tim, that solved my question, and now i learned a new function rank:-)